# Using MSBuild.exe to deploy MVC Project fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, msbuild, web-deployment

I am using MSBuild.exe in Powershell to build and deploy MVC5 application in VS Pro 2017. The command is

```
&"$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" $solutionFilePath `
            /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 `
            /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
            /p:PublishProfile=$publishXmlFile `
            /p:Password=$password
```

The value of the variables are correct and publish profile is fine too. But I am getting build error in PS which says

> C:\MyLib\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.wap.targets(50,5): error MSB4062: The "ReadWebJobsConfigFile" task could not be
>    loaded from the assembly C:\MyLib\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.Tasks.dll. Could not load file 
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system 
>   cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that 
>   the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\MyLib\TestMVCProject\TestMVCProject.c
>   sproj]

Any help on this?

Comment: Try using msbuild.exe under IDE folder like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe . For vs2017 projects, sometimes the msbuild tool under framework can't work well. And for vs2017,the vsversion should be 15.0. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. If you can write this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Good news. I'm glad it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.For VS2017. Usually, we use the msbuild.exe under IDE folder like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe instead of that under framework folder because the tool within IDE works better.

2.For vs2017, the version is 15. And for vs2017, it's 14,etc...
Thank you.